# How to hide/show Bottom Navigation View during webview Scroll

Tags: android, webview, bottomnavigationview

i have a BottomNavigationView activity . in that i placed a webview as fragment , but the problem is ,user can not click on the web contents on the bottom side, because of my BottomNavigationView , is there any one to suggest me a good solution

[image: screenshot]

this is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        />

</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

this is my webview fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial.tab1">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:foregroundGravity="top"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
        android:progress="20"/>

</FrameLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">






    <com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial.EulaWebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />



</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

[image: after adding answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a Custom scrolling behaviour for the `BottomNavigationView` which allow you to hide it during scroll.

From [Link](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/bottom-navigation-behavior-388b9b206667)

```
 public final class BottomNavigationBehavior<V extends View> extends VerticalScrollingBehavior<V> {
    private static final Interpolator INTERPOLATOR = new LinearOutSlowInInterpolator();
    private final BottomNavigationWithSnackbar mWithSnackBarImpl = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? new LollipopBottomNavWithSnackBarImpl() : new PreLollipopBottomNavWithSnackBarImpl();
    private boolean isTablet;
    private int mTabLayoutId;
    private boolean hidden = false;
    private ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat mOffsetValueAnimator;
    private ViewGroup mTabLayout;
    private View mTabsHolder;
    private int mSnackbarHeight = -1;
    private boolean scrollingEnabled = true;
    private boolean hideAlongSnackbar = false;
    int[] attrsArray = new int[] {
            android.R.attr.id };
    public BottomNavigationBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    public BottomNavigationBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                attrsArray);
        mTabLayoutId = a.getResourceId(0, View.NO_ID);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public static <V extends View> BottomNavigationBehavior<V> from(@NonNull V view) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        if (!(params instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout");
        }
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) params)
                .getBehavior();
        if (!(behavior instanceof BottomNavigationBehavior)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The view is not associated with BottomNavigationBehavior");
        }
        return (BottomNavigationBehavior<V>) behavior;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, View dependency) {
        mWithSnackBarImpl.updateSnackbar(parent, dependency, child);
        return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDependentViewRemoved(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, View dependency) {
        updateScrollingForSnackbar(dependency, child, true);
        super.onDependentViewRemoved(parent, child, dependency);
    }

    private void updateScrollingForSnackbar(View dependency, V child, boolean enabled) {
        if (!isTablet && dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
            scrollingEnabled = enabled;
            if (!hideAlongSnackbar && ViewCompat.getTranslationY(child) != 0) {
                ViewCompat.setTranslationY(child, 0);
                hidden = false;
                hideAlongSnackbar = true;
            }else if(hideAlongSnackbar){
                hidden = true;
                animateOffset(child, -child.getHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, View dependency) {
        updateScrollingForSnackbar(dependency, child, false);
        return super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, child, dependency);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, int layoutDirection) {
        boolean layoutChild = super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
        if (mTabLayout == null && mTabLayoutId != View.NO_ID) {
            mTabLayout = findTabLayout(child);
            getTabsHolder();
        }

        return layoutChild;
    }

    @Nullable
    private ViewGroup findTabLayout(@NonNull View child) {
        if (mTabLayoutId == 0) return null;
        return (ViewGroup) child.findViewById(mTabLayoutId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedVerticalOverScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, @ScrollDirection int direction, int currentOverScroll, int totalOverScroll) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, @ScrollDirection int scrollDirection) {
        handleDirection(child, scrollDirection);
    }

    private void handleDirection(V child, @ScrollDirection int scrollDirection) {
        if (!scrollingEnabled) return;
        if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN && hidden) {
            hidden = false;
            animateOffset(child, 0);
        } else if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP && !hidden) {
            hidden = true;
            animateOffset(child, child.getHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onNestedDirectionFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, @ScrollDirection int scrollDirection) {
        handleDirection(child, scrollDirection);
        return true;
    }

    private void animateOffset(final V child, final int offset) {
        ensureOrCancelAnimator(child);
        mOffsetValueAnimator.translationY(offset).start();
        animateTabsHolder(offset);
    }

    private void animateTabsHolder(int offset) {
        if (mTabsHolder != null) {
            offset = offset > 0 ? 0 : 1;
            ViewCompat.animate(mTabsHolder).alpha(offset).setDuration(200).start();
        }
    }

    private void ensureOrCancelAnimator(V child) {
        if (mOffsetValueAnimator == null) {
            mOffsetValueAnimator = ViewCompat.animate(child);
            mOffsetValueAnimator.setDuration(100);
            mOffsetValueAnimator.setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR);
        } else {
            mOffsetValueAnimator.cancel();
        }
    }

    private void getTabsHolder() {
        if (mTabLayout != null) {
            mTabsHolder = mTabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        }
    }

    public boolean isScrollingEnabled() {
        return scrollingEnabled;
    }

    public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean scrollingEnabled) {
        this.scrollingEnabled = scrollingEnabled;
    }

    public void setHidden(V view, boolean bottomLayoutHidden) {
        if (!bottomLayoutHidden && hidden) {
            animateOffset(view, 0);
        } else if (bottomLayoutHidden && !hidden) {
            animateOffset(view, -view.getHeight());
        }
        hidden = bottomLayoutHidden;
    }

    private interface BottomNavigationWithSnackbar {
        void updateSnackbar(CoordinatorLayout parent, View dependency, View child);
    }

    private class PreLollipopBottomNavWithSnackBarImpl implements BottomNavigationWithSnackbar {

        @Override
        public void updateSnackbar(CoordinatorLayout parent, View dependency, View child) {
            if (!isTablet && dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
                if (mSnackbarHeight == -1) {
                    mSnackbarHeight = dependency.getHeight();
                }

                int targetPadding = child.getMeasuredHeight();

                int shadow = (int) ViewCompat.getElevation(child);
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) dependency.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = targetPadding - shadow;
                child.bringToFront();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    child.getParent().requestLayout();
                    ((View) child.getParent()).invalidate();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private class LollipopBottomNavWithSnackBarImpl implements BottomNavigationWithSnackbar {

        @Override
        public void updateSnackbar(CoordinatorLayout parent, View dependency, View child) {
            if (!isTablet && dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
                if (mSnackbarHeight == -1) {
                    mSnackbarHeight = dependency.getHeight();
                }
                int targetPadding = (mSnackbarHeight +
                        child.getMeasuredHeight());
                dependency.setPadding(dependency.getPaddingLeft(),
                        dependency.getPaddingTop(), dependency.getPaddingRight(), targetPadding
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

apply it in your view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior=".BottomNavigationBehavior"  //apply the behaviour
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

output:

[image]

Comment: its not working bro, after adding your code, it is gone , the navigation

Comment: you didn't add the `Framelayout`...didn't you replace the Framelayout with your webview fragment...?

Comment: Because i don't want the Text view which is inside the frame layout

Comment: Or i should add the framelayout??

Comment: you can remove the textview inside framelayout...that's why i asked did you replace the framelayout with your webview...

Comment: OK, I removed text view , but frame layout is still there,

Comment: i should add the webview inside the frame layout in the activity_main.xml

Comment: you can try remove the <FrameLayout> tag and replace it with `<WebView`..i have edited it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141279/discussion-between-rafsanahmad007-and-jaison-joseph).

Comment: What i hv done is, added a frame layout above bottom navigation  which is empty . And relative layout as it is

Answer (score -1):

So easy, use `CoordinatorLayout`.

---

**1. Change your root View to CoordinatorLayout**

- Remember to add the dependency in gradle file:

  ```
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
  ```

---

**2. Wrapping Content View into NestedScrollView**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView                  //or use ScrollView with "android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"", see below
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView_webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

---

**3. Adding "layout_behavior" to your Bottom View**

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior">
```

Comment: not recommended to use inside the scroll view

Comment: @Anil Ugale Can you explain why? It works for me at least.

Comment: WebView in side-scrolling error pron when using Ifrom in web side